# local users and groups output to a file

Tags: file, powershell

I have a script that shows all the local users and their associated groups.   However, I'm trying to output the results into a text file and that's where the script goes wrong, because it's not giving me the same results I'm receiving from the output window.  For example, the code I have reads:

```psh
$LogFile = Test-Path C:\Users\FredAslami\Downloads\Test.txt
$LocalUsers = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"

if ($LogFile) {
  $LocalUsers.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | Foreach-Object {
    $groups = $_.Groups() | Foreach-Object {
      $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
    }
    $_ | Select-Object @{n='UserName';e={$_.Name}},
                       @{n='Groups';e={$groups -join ';'}}
  }

  Write-Host "Got User Groups Info"

  Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\FredAslami\Downloads\Test.txt `
    -InputObject $LocalUsers -Append

  Write-Host "Added info to text"
}

$LocalUsers.Dispose()
```

When I run that the text in the file will read

```
distinguishedName : 
Path              : WinNT://R68-CUSTOM-01
```

I have also tried using `Add-Content`, but that doesn't work either. It will add something like:

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
```

I also, tried to debug using `Write-Host` after it retrieves the local users and group info and another `Write-Host` after it writes the results into the text file and noticed that it's writing the results before it gathered all the info. So I tried using the `Start-Sleep`, and that didnt seem to work.

Comment: Does your complex line on `$LocalUsers.Children` modify the `$LocalUsers` collection?  If not, then you're dumping the changes to the console but not storing them.  Then you're writing the original `$LocalUsers` to Out-File.

Comment: I didnt realize that, thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second line you have `$LocalUsers = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"`. You never assigned it a different value, so that's what you're seeing as your output.

I would recommend piping your `Select-Object` statement to `Export-Csv`. Much easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You get different results in screen and file output, because you're doing different things with your data. The pipeline starting with `$localUsers.Children` builds a list of the user objects and their group memberships and echoes that to the screen, but you don't do anything else with that data. Instead you're writing the unmodified variable `$localUsers` to the output file.

If you want tabular data to go both to the console and a file, I'd suggest using `Write-Host` for the console output, and `Export-Csv` for the file output:

```psh
$LocalUsers.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | Foreach-Object {
  $groups = $_.Groups() | Foreach-Object {
    $_.GetType().InvokeMember('Name', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
  }
  $o = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
         'UserName' = $_.Name
         'Groups'   = $groups -join ';'
       }
  Write-Host $o
  $o
} | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\FredAslami\Downloads\Test.txt' -NoType
```

If you want the output to go to the success output stream instead of the console, you could capture the result in a variable and output that in two different ways:

```psh
$users = $LocalUsers.Children | where {
           $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'
         } | Foreach-Object {
           $groups = $_.Groups() | Foreach-Object {
             $_.GetType().InvokeMember('Name', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
           }
           New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
             'UserName' = $_.Name
             'Groups'   = $groups -join ';'
           }
         }

$users
$users | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\FredAslami\Downloads\Test.txt' -NoType
```